# Losing focus when changing workspace

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, xfce, workspaces

I've got an irritating issue with losing focus on **xubuntu 18.04** while changing workspaces. Lets assume, that I've got 2 displays and 2 workspaces. Active windows are arranged like this:

```
                 [Workspace 1]
   [display 1]                   [display 2]

 Terminal                   PhpStorm Project #2
 PhpStorm Project #1        Chrome Window #1

                 [Workspace 2]
   [display 1]                   [display 2]

Settings Window             Spotify
Chrome Window #2
```

1. While being on *"Workspace 1"*, I've got active "PhpStorm Project #2", so the Chrome window is under that active window. Also, terminal is above "PhpStorm Project #1".
2. Now, I'm moving to *"Workspace 2"*. Here I have settings window active and Spotify.
3. Next step: going back to *"Workspace 1"*. Content on display 1 has not changed, but suddenly I've got Chrome window active instead of "PhpStorm Project #2". Also, PhpStorm should be active, but instead of that, an active window is the Terminal :D. In other cases, Chrome is stealing that focus.

What is wrong? How to deal with that problem?

I'm using Xfce v4.12 interface.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with PHPStorm on Xubuntu 16.04 (for a few months now).

Comment: I've edited this question to removed your second question, as we like to stick to a single question at a time, and I think it is already asked here if you search for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194124) with PhpStorm and IntelliJ platform in general.

In order to fix it, as per comments in their issue tracker, you need to add this to [`idea.properties`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/file-idea-properties.html) file: `suppress.focus.stealing=false` and restart PhpStorm.

I had the same problem on Debian with XFCE and this solved it for me.

Comment: Oh... my... god.... it's working :D. I've been waiting for this day for sooo long.

Comment: For reference, you can edit the idea.properties file by going Help -> Edit Custom Properties... in the menu.  Easier than making sure you find the right hidden directory and creating the file manually.